# How to hide the keyboard with onTap the screen?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, focus, hide

While using the text fields in flutter,
how we can able to hide the keyboard after its use just by tapping on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **FocusNode**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
       FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); to hide the keyboard. Wrap entire Scaffold with Gesture detector and on tap make use of FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); to hide the keyboard on tap of any part of the screen.

Please refer below working code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
       
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // To hide the keyboard
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Example Text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```